# How to Automatically Show/Hide Divs on Page Load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create sort of slideshow of customer testimonials. On page load, I'd like to show/hide next testimonial every few seconds. I've got example working, but only using click method. Maybe someone could point out how to make this work without click, but rather automatically on page load?

I tried replacing .click with .ready/.load, but nothing happens.

```js
$(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().fadeOut(500).next().delay(500).fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

```css
section {
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #ADD3C9;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
button {
    display: block;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#p2,#p3,#p4 {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="p1">
    <div>Content for  class "1" Goes Here</div>
  <button>Next</button>
</section>

<section id="p2">
    <div>Content for  class "2" Goes Here</div>
  <button>Next</button>
</section>

<section id="p3">
  <div>Content for  class "3" Goes Here</div>
  <button>Next</button>
</section>

<section id="p4">
  <div>Content for  class "4" Goes Here</div>
</section>
```

Comment: you can use `setInterval` and `setTimeout`

Comment: thanx, I've got it to move, but problem now is it's showing all other sections at once after fade.

setInterval(function(){ 
$('section').fadeOut(500).next().delay(500).fadeIn(500);}, 3000);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
  setInterval(function() {
        $('section:not(#p4)[style*="display: flex"]').fadeOut(500).next().delay(500).fadeIn(500);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
section {
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #ADD3C9;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
button {
    display: block;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#p2,#p3,#p4 {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="p1" style="display: flex;">
    <div>Content for  class "1" Goes Here</div>
  <button>Next</button>
</section>

<section id="p2">
    <div>Content for  class "2" Goes Here</div>
  <button>Next</button>
</section>

<section id="p3">
  <div>Content for  class "3" Goes Here</div>
  <button>Next</button>
</section>

<section id="p4">
  <div>Content for  class "4" Goes Here</div>
</section>
```